# auto-responder with login details in Symfony

Tags: symfony, mailer

Here is the funcion im using

```
 public function sendCredentialsEmailMessage(UserInterface $user)
    {
        $template = 'Emails/afterRegister.html.twig';

        $rendered = $this->templating->render($template, array(
            'user'     => $user,
        ));

        $this->sendEmailMessage($rendered,
            $this->parameters['from_email']['confirmation'], $user->getEmail());
    }
```

Basically I want the auto-mailer to send my template along with the login name. When i create a new user nothing is being sent. My email template is located in app>resources>views>emails>

and this controller file is located in src>myname>userbundle>mailer>

```
protected function sendEmailMessage($renderedTemplate, $fromEmail, $toEmail)
{
    // Render the email, use the first line as the subject, and the rest as the body
    $renderedLines = explode("\n", trim($renderedTemplate));
    $subject       = array_shift($renderedLines);
    $body          = implode("\n", $renderedLines);

    $message = (new \Swift_Message())
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setFrom($fromEmail)
        ->setTo($toEmail)
        ->setBody($body);

    $this->mailer->send($message);
}
```

Also this works for sure:

```
public function sendResettingEmailMessage(UserInterface $user)
{
    $template = $this->parameters['resetting.template'];
    $url      = $this->router->generate('fos_user_resetting_reset', array('token' => $user->getConfirmationToken()),
        UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
    $rendered = $this->templating->render($template, array(
        'user'            => $user,
        'confirmationUrl' => $url,
    ));
    $this->sendEmailMessageCustom($rendered,  $this->from, (string)$user->getEmail(),'Password resseting');
}
```

Comment: You generally get better help on stackoverflow if you also give some idea of what you have tried.  Have you verified that the mailer is properly configured and does indeed send emails?  Have you verified that sendCredentialsEmailMessage is being called?

Comment: added more code, which one of functions works for sure. Im a total newb trying to config my already built website, if this is not the right place, please point me another one where I can freely ask, thanks

Comment: This is the right place for this sort of question.  Just needed a few more details.  Since your reset works we can conclude that your mailer is properly configured as well as your templates.  That is encouraging.  You do have a sendEmailMessageCustom as well as a sendEmailMessage so there might be something going on there.  Have you verified that sendCredentialsEmailMessage is being called?  Does your email perhaps show up in the debug bar?

Comment: What is the best way to check debug in symfony? As I said i took over the side after few guys created basics but didnt finish and Im trying to achieve that.

Comment: At some point you are just going to need to take a step back and [read the docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/profiler.html).  Make sure you select the correct Symfony version.